Correlated sampling of Pauli twirling operators
In standard treatments of randomized compiling, each gate layer is twirled with a twirling operator that is sampled uniformly at random from the Pauli group. Twirled gates can be combined modularly by ensuring that the twirling operators are sampled independently.
However, what happens if we violate this condition? What if our sampled twirling operators obey certain correlations, e.g., over an algorithm of even depth, the twirling operators obey a time reversal symmetry? Will only noise that is itself exhibits time-reversal correlations fail to randomize?
NB: The aforementioned example gives rise to homogeneous polynomials that are quadratic in the twirling Pauli, but the Paulis form only a 1-design.
